# Changing default sort order in Windows 7 desktop search

Tags: windows-7, sorting, windows-search

If I do a search (usually, I'm looking for an email), the results are presented in date-modified order by default

I can do Sort By / More... and select Date Received, then Sort By and select Date Received, but I have to do this every time

So can I change the default sort order? Or, failing that, can I get Date Received in the list that appears on the Sort By menu, without having to go through More...?

Comment: In my experience (just confirmed), whatever columns I add to the Search view "stick" and show up every time I search subsequently, in any location. The sort order is remembered correctly as well.

Comment: I'm not adding columns and I don't really want to, I want the Content view not the Details one. I'm right clicking and choosing sort-by. Those don't seem to be remembered...

Comment: Ah, that may well be the case (I'll check later when I'm on my Windows PC). I don't use Content view so perhaps that has this limitation for some reason, or maybe it's just a bug.

Comment: Content view shows a bit of each email. I use Windows search to find emails almost exclusively so that's vital to me

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, erratic sorting by Date even when Date was selected in Content View.

Once I changed to Detailed View, sorted the Date column by ascending order, and then switched back to Content view, that sorting appears to have stuck for all future sorts, even in content view.

HTH,
D

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'll give that a go.